# escaping single quotes for ajax calls

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a php page which is called via AJAX. and basically it fetches some value from my database and echos back at table with inputs etc. The problem is when the string it fetches contains quotation marks(actually only single quotes seem to be effected). So on the php page there's something like this:

```
$value  = htmlentities($DB_result->cloumn);

echo'<input type = "button" onClick = "$(\'#something\').val(\''.$value.'\');" />'
```

so if `$value` = "hello", no problems but if: `$value` = 'hello', the page which I'm making the AJAX call from throws up some such error: Syntax Error: unexpected identifier.
so I guess the quotations in $value have not been escaped, which I thought it would with the `htmlentities`. any Ideas how to solve this much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: simplest solution is don't mix obtrusive and unobtrusive javascript. Why are using using jQuery if you want your script inline?

Comment: very little is inline, but for this particular purpose it is the best solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `$value` contains single quotes, which interfere with the correct parsing of javascript. from [the manual entry for html entities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php):

> all characters which have HTML character entity equivalents are translated into these entities.

this means that your single quotes are not escaped, they are only translated in a way browsers will better understand. You need to use `addslashes()`:

```
$value  = htmlentities(addslashes($DB_result->cloumn));
```

`"'hello'"` will become `"\'hello\'"` which in the browser will look like:

```
<input type = "button" onClick = "$('#something').val('\'hello\'');" />
```

which will attribute the string `'hello'` (with the single quotes) to the value attribute of `$('#something')`

Comment: while reading about htmlentities, tell me if I'm wrong: it does not escapes values, it just tells html what they are in a clearer way. single quotes will still be single quotes, and will still be evaluated as such. from http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php: "all characters which have HTML character entity equivalents are translated into these entities."

Comment: nice idea, unfortunately no change though. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: try with addslashes inside of html entities. it's possible addslashes won't recognize slashes as such when translated as html entities.

Comment: I'm no expert, you probably know more. It was my understanding that htmlentities basically convertered html to text so symbols like <> had no special significance like they do in html

Comment: Good thinking, and good result. it's done the trick, just one snag, its actually showing the \ symbol, but I can fix that I reckon. html is truly a minefield. Thank you ever so much.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$value  = htmlentities($DB_result->cloumn, ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8");
```

Passing ENT_QUOTES through as a flag will convert both double and single quotes.

Comment: @user2014429 Then you're going to have to show us the resulting HTML.

Comment: there's not much to show really, basically, if you click the button, as shown in example above, it throws up an error, upexpected, or ILLEGAL syntax error usually, that is if the result has single quotes. and $('#something') doesn't get filled.

Comment: @user2014429 What does the resulting HTML source look like after your page has loaded?

Comment: @Waynee Whitty the actual elements are all there, it's just the onClick attribute of those elements that is effected

Comment: Can you show us the HTML source of the button after the page has loaded? That will give everyone the best indication of what is wrong.

Comment: Just View Source in your browser after the page has loaded and copy and paste the HTML of your button above.